# Filtering vcf file with own python code IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, vcf-vcard

In order to filter my vcf file I created some kind of code to filter that vcf file concerning heterozygosity, missing data and low quality. I defined two functions that take as input my gzipped vcf file and as output a new created vcf file. I included the paths into the `gzip.open` command.

I have following python code in order to filter a .vcf file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import numpy as np
import gzip


def whole_vcf(thresh):
    vcf=gzip.open("/my/path/to/file/myfile.vcf.gz","r")
    remlist=[]
    het_dp=[]
    total_dp=[]
    hetcount=0
    totalcount=0
    while True:
        line=vcf.readline()
        if line=="":
            break
        if line[0]=="#":
            continue
        totalcount+=1
        line=line.split(b"\t")
        loc_id=line[2]
        chr=line[0]
        pos=line[1]
        gt=[x.split(":")[0] for x in line[9::]]
        het_count=gt.count("0/1")+gt.count("1/0")
        ref_count=gt.count("0/0")
        alt_count=gt.count("1/1")
        gt_total=len(gt)-gt.count("./.")
        het_ratio=het_count/float(gt_total)
        ref_ratio=ref_count/float(gt_total)
        alt_ratio=alt_count/float(gt_total)
        dp=[x.split(":")[3] for x in line[9::]]
        while "." in dp:
            dp.remove(".")
        for i,d in enumerate(dp):
            dp[i]=int(d)
        dp_site_mean=np.nanmean(dp)
        if het_ratio>=thresh:
            hetcount+=1
            het_dp.append(dp_site_mean)
            remlist.append((chr,pos))
        else:
            total_dp.append(dp_site_mean)
    print("Depth in sites >={0}% heterozygous:".format(thresh*100),np.mean(het_dp))
    print("Depth in other sites:",np.nanmean(total_dp))
    print("% of >{0}% heterozyous sites:".format(thresh*100),hetcount*100/float(totalcount))
    vcf.close()
    return remlist


def write_out(remlist):
    out=gzip.open("/my/path/to/file/myfile_out.vcf.gz","w")
    vcf=gzip.open("/my/path/to/file/myfile.vcf.gz","r")
    for line in vcf:
        if line[0]=="#":
            out.write(line)
        else:
            chr=line.split("\t")[0]
            pos=line.split("\t")[1]
            if (chr,pos) not in remlist:
                out.write(line)

remlist=whole_vcf(0.2)
remlist=set(remlist)
write_out(remlist)
```

My .vcf file looks like this:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.2
##ALT=<ID=NON_REF,Description="Represents any possible alternative allele not already represented at this location by REF and ALT">
##FILTER=<ID=LowQual,Description="Low quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=AD,Number=R,Type=Integer,Description="Allelic depths for the ref and alt alleles in the order listed">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Approximate read depth (reads with MQ=255 or with bad mates are filtered)">
##FORMAT=<ID=GQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Genotype Quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=MIN_DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Minimum DP observed within the GVCF block">
##FORMAT=<ID=PGT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Physical phasing haplotype information, describing how the alternate alleles are phased in relation to one another; will always be heterozygous and is not intended to describe called alleles">
##FORMAT=<ID=PID,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Physical phasing ID information, where each unique ID within a given sample (but not across samples) connects records within a phasing group">
##FORMAT=<ID=PL,Number=G,Type=Integer,Description="Normalized, Phred-scaled likelihoods for genotypes as defined in the VCF specification">
##FORMAT=<ID=PS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Phasing set (typically the position of the first variant in the set)">
##FORMAT=<ID=RGQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Unconditional reference genotype confidence, encoded as a phred quality -10*log10 p(genotype call is wrong)">
##FORMAT=<ID=SB,Number=4,Type=Integer,Description="Per-sample component statistics which comprise the Fisher's Exact Test to detect strand bias.">
##GATKCommandLine=<ID=CombineGVCFs,CommandLine="CombineGVCFs ">
##GATKCommandLine=<ID=GenotypeGVCFs,CommandLine="GenotypeGVCFs">
##INFO=<ID=AC,Number=A,Type=Integer,Description="Allele count in genotypes, for each ALT allele, in the same order as listed">
##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele Frequency, for each ALT allele, in the same order as listed">
##INFO=<ID=AN,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total number of alleles in called genotypes">
##INFO=<ID=BaseQRankSum,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Z-score from Wilcoxon rank sum test of Alt Vs. Ref base qualities">
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Approximate read depth; some reads may have been filtered">
##INFO=<ID=END,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Stop position of the interval">
##INFO=<ID=ExcessHet,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Phred-scaled p-value for exact test of excess heterozygosity">
##INFO=<ID=FS,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Phred-scaled p-value using Fisher's exact test to detect strand bias">
##INFO=<ID=InbreedingCoeff,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Inbreeding coefficient as estimated from the genotype likelihoods per-sample when compared against the Hardy-Weinberg expectation">
##INFO=<ID=MLEAC,Number=A,Type=Integer,Description="Maximum likelihood expectation (MLE) for the allele counts (not necessarily the same as the AC), for each ALT allele, in the same order as listed">
##INFO=<ID=MLEAF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Maximum likelihood expectation (MLE) for the allele frequency (not necessarily the same as the AF), for each ALT allele, in the same order as listed">
##INFO=<ID=MQ,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="RMS Mapping Quality">
##INFO=<ID=MQRankSum,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Z-score From Wilcoxon rank sum test of Alt vs. Ref read mapping qualities">
##INFO=<ID=QD,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Variant Confidence/Quality by Depth">
##INFO=<ID=RAW_MQandDP,Number=2,Type=Integer,Description="Raw data (sum of squared MQ and total depth) for improved RMS Mapping Quality calculation. Incompatible with deprecated RAW_MQ formulation.">
##INFO=<ID=ReadPosRankSum,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Z-score from Wilcoxon rank sum test of Alt vs. Ref read position bias">
##INFO=<ID=SOR,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Symmetric Odds Ratio of 2x2 contingency table to detect strand bias">
##contig=<ID=8,length=36828865>
##contig=<ID=1,length=25094922>
##contig=<ID=3,length=24765164>
##contig=<ID=4,length=26989988>
##contig=<ID=7,length=23031378>
##contig=<ID=5,length=19675369>
##contig=<ID=6,length=17480895>
##contig=<ID=2,length=18260876>
##source=CombineGVCFs
##source=GenotypeGVCFs
##source=HaplotypeCaller
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  10_cliprem_cleansorted  114_cliprem_cleansorted 116_cliprem_cleansorted 163_cliprem_cleansorted 173_cliprem_cleansorted 174_cliprem_cleansorted 175_cliprem_cleansorted 176_cliprem_cleansorted 177_cliprem_cleansorted 19_cliprem_cleansorted  233_cliprem_cleansorted 25_cliprem_cleansorted  261_cliprem_cleansorted 267_cliprem_cleansorted 271_cliprem_cleansorted 272_cliprem_cleansorted 277_cliprem_cleansorted 293_cliprem_cleansorted 29_cliprem_cleansorted  309_cliprem_cleansorted 30_cliprem_cleansorted  323_cliprem_cleansorted 326_cliprem_cleansorted 337_cliprem_cleansorted 344_cliprem_cleansorted 34_cliprem_cleansorted  358_cliprem_cleansorted 359_cliprem_cleansorted 360_cliprem_cleansorted 370_cliprem_cleansorted 380_cliprem_cleansorted 393_cliprem_cleansorted 435_cliprem_cleansorted 69_cliprem_cleansorted  72_cliprem_cleansorted  94_cliprem_cleansorted
8   370 .   T   C   38.72   .   AC=1;AF=0.033;AN=30;BaseQRankSum=-3.052e+00;DP=179;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=2.452;InbreedingCoeff=0.4221;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=0.067;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=2.15;ReadPosRankSum=-2.082e+00;SOR=0.188 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:13,0:13:36:0,36,540 ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/0:7,0:7:21:0,21,240   0/0:1,0:1:3:0,3,42  ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:0,3,37  0/0:19,0:19:45:0,45,675 0/0:9,0:9:24:0,24,360   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/0:16,0:16:45:0,45,675 0/0:36,0:36:99:0,108,1129   0/0:16,0:16:48:0,48,656 0/0:5,0:5:15:0,15,197   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/1:14,4:18:45:45,0,493 ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/0:14,0:14:42:0,42,456 ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:0,3,42  0/0:8,0:8:24:0,24,322   0/0:15,0:15:45:0,45,603 ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0
8   552 .   G   C   316.42  .   AC=10;AF=0.294;AN=34;DP=203;ExcessHet=0.0001;FS=0.000;InbreedingCoeff=0.5221;MLEAC=13;MLEAF=0.382;MQ=39.27;QD=25.36;SOR=3.056   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:10,0:10:0:0,0,322   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/0:17,0:17:51:0,51,562 ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   1/1:0,2:2:6:84,6,0  ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/0:21,0:21:57:0,57,855 0/0:11,0:11:33:0,33,435 ./.:1,0:1:.:0,0,0   1/1:0,2:2:6:49,6,0  ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:2,0:2:.:0,0,0   0/0:21,0:21:60:0,60,858 0/0:36,0:36:99:0,108,1129   0/0:16,0:16:48:0,48,644 0/0:8,0:8:24:0,24,308   1/1:0,3:3:9:113,9,0 1/1:0,1:1:3:42,3,0  0/0:21,0:21:48:0,48,718 1/1:0,1:1:3:42,3,0  ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/0:7,0:7:21:0,21,254   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   0/0:3,0:3:9:0,9,99  0/0:19,0:19:57:0,57,767 ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   ./.:1,0:1:.:0,0,0
8   592 .   A   G   677.28  .   AC=14;AF=0.350;AN=40;DP=226;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=0.000;InbreedingCoeff=0.5889;MLEAC=16;MLEAF=0.400;MQ=41.77;QD=28.73;SOR=2.049   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL:PS   0/0:10,0:10:30:.:.:0,30,418:.   ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:15,0:15:45:.:.:0,45,580:.   1|1:0,3:3:9:1|1:592_A_G:135,9,0:592 ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 1|1:0,5:5:15:1|1:592_A_G:225,15,0:592   ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:24,0:24:72:.:.:0,72,1039:.  0/0:12,0:12:36:.:.:0,36,441:.   1/1:0,1:1:3:.:.:25,3,0:.    1|1:0,2:2:6:1|1:592_A_G:90,6,0:592  ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:8,0:8:9:.:.:0,9,277:.   0/0:23,0:23:66:.:.:0,66,990:.   0/0:36,0:36:99:.:.:0,108,1129:. 0/0:21,0:21:21:.:.:0,21,767:.   0/0:7,0:7:21:.:.:0,21,292:. 1|1:0,3:3:9:1|1:592_A_G:135,9,0:592 1/1:0,1:1:3:.:.:42,3,0:.    0/0:19,0:19:51:.:.:0,51,765:.   1|1:0,1:1:3:1|1:592_A_G:45,3,0:592  ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:11,0:11:33:.:.:0,33,421:.   ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:4,0:4:12:.:.:0,12,155:. 0/0:19,0:19:54:.:.:0,54,810:.   ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:1,0:1:.:.:.:0,0,0:.
8   610 .   C   G   600.88  .   AC=10;AF=0.250;AN=40;DP=251;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=0.000;InbreedingCoeff=0.5842;MLEAC=12;MLEAF=0.300;MQ=40.60;QD=30.97;SOR=1.765   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL:PS   0/0:13,0:13:39:.:.:0,39,531:.   ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:15,0:15:42:.:.:0,42,630:.   1|1:0,3:3:9:1|1:592_A_G:135,9,0:592 ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 1|1:0,5:5:15:1|1:592_A_G:225,15,0:592   ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:32,0:32:81:.:.:0,81,1215:.  0/0:14,0:14:36:.:.:0,36,540:.   ./.:4,0:4:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 1|1:0,2:2:6:1|1:592_A_G:90,6,0:592  0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,74:.    ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:9,0:9:27:.:.:0,27,376:. 0/0:24,0:24:63:.:.:0,63,945:.   0/0:36,0:36:99:.:.:0,108,1129:. 0/0:20,0:20:54:.:.:0,54,810:.   0/0:8,0:8:24:.:.:0,24,296:. 1|1:0,3:3:9:1|1:592_A_G:135,9,0:592 ./.:2,0:2:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:18,0:18:12:.:.:0,12,656:.   1|1:0,1:1:3:1|1:592_A_G:45,3,0:592  ./.:3,0:3:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:12,0:12:36:.:.:0,36,463:.   ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,42:.    ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. 0/0:4,0:4:12:.:.:0,12,155:. 0/0:19,0:19:57:.:.:0,57,741:.   ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:0,0:0:.:.:.:0,0,0:. ./.:1,0:1:.:.:.:0,0,0:.
```

When running my script with: `python vcf_het_genedup_wgs.py`

I always get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vcf_het_genedup_wgs.py", line 72, in <module>
    remlist=whole_vcf(0.2)
  File "vcf_het_genedup_wgs.py", line 30, in whole_vcf
    loc_id=line[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Obviously it is not taking the correct input, but I don't understand why exactly.

Comment: Put a print statement above the line `loc_id=line[2]` to see what it actually contains, like `print(line)`.  Or better yet, if you're feeling adventurious, put `breakpoint()` and drop into the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Apparently it cannot the error `list index out of range` occurs because it cannot open the `line[>0]`. Meaning that `line[0]` is working, but `line[1]` or `line[2]` gives me the error. Can you imagine why?

Comment: Does it actually contain tabs?

Comment: Hi, yes it does. The `line` object looks like this: `[b'8' , b'370' , b'.' ... etc]`